# Need help visualizing a linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, visualization

I've been trying to understand singly linked list.

What would be the difference between setting variables such as

```
cur=head
prev=head
```

do to the variable `cur` and `prev`? and

how is the `prev.next =cur.next`

affecting the linked list? How can I visualize it?

```
    cur=head
    prev=head
    c=0
    while(end!=None):
        end=end.next
        c+=1
    print(c)
    mark=c-n
    if mark==0:
        head=head.next    

    while(mark>0):
        prev=cur
        cur=cur.next
        mark-=1
    prev.next=cur.next
    return head
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume the sample list `1->2->3->4->5` throughout this explanation.

This algorithm removes the `n`th node from the end of a linked list. The first part of the code simply finds and prints the length of the list (I'm assuming `c` is short for "count"):

```
c=0
while(end!=None):
    end=end.next
    c+=1
print(c)
```

Note that there's a missing variable `end`, which is a runner node used to traverse the list and must have been initialized like `end = head`. After `end` walks the list, `c = 5`.

---

Let's walk through the main node removal logic on the sample list. The first part,

```
if mark==0:
    head=head.next
```

handles an edge case where we need to remove the head of the list. `n` must be equal to the length of the list, or in this example, 5, meaning we want to remove the 5th-to-last node. Here, were simply set `head` to its next element, which removes all references to the `1` node. It will be garbage collected at some point after this operation.

```
before:
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
    ^    
    |    
   head
```

```
after:
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
                ^    
                |    
               head
```

```
the resulting list:
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
    ^    
    |    
   head
```

---

As for the typical case as described in

```
while(mark>0):
    prev=cur
    cur=cur.next
    mark-=1
prev.next=cur.next
```

where the element to remove is not the head, let's walk through an example with `n = 2`. In this case, we want to remove the second to last node from `1->2->3->4->5`, or `4`.

Before the `while` loop starts, here's what `prev`, `cur` and `head` point to:

```
   head
     |
     v
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
  ^    ^
  |    |
prev  cur
```

On the first iteration, `prev` is set to `cur`:

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
  ^    ^
  |    |
 prev cur

mark = 3
```

Then, `cur` is set to its next node:

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
    ^            ^
    |            |
   prev         cur

mark = 3
```

The same thing is done two more times:

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
              ^    ^
              |    |
            prev  cur

mark = 2
```

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
                 ^            ^
                 |            |
                prev         cur

mark = 2
```

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
                          ^    ^
                          |    |
                         prev cur

mark = 1
```

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+
                            ^            ^
                            |            |
                           prev         cur

mark = 1
```

At this point, the loop breaks because `mark` is decremented to 0. You can see that our nodes are in perfect position to unlink `4` from the list with `prev.next=cur.next`. Let's do it:

```
                                   +------------------+
                                   |                  |
                                   |                  v
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+ |  +--------+  +--------+
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 | |  | val: 4 |  | val: 5 |
| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---+  | next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+    +--------+  +--------+
                            ^              ^ 
                            |              |
                           prev           cur
```

The node pointed to by `cur` with the value of `4` is inaccessible and has nothing referencing it. It will be garbage collected by the interpreter at some point in the future. Now that it is no longer part of the list, we're left with this result when the code finishes:

```
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+ 
| val: 1 |  | val: 2 |  | val: 3 |  | val: 5 |  
| next: --->| next: --->| next: --->| next: ---> [None]
+--------+  +--------+  +--------+  +--------+  
     ^
     |
   head
```

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much. So in linked list, you use other pointers to keep the head pointing to original head.

Comment: That's right, you've got it. When you see `cur = head`, that just says "create another pointer (reference) to the node object that `head` points to". You then use these pointers to move through and/or modify the list.

Answer (score 0):

Think of elements(nodes) as boxes. Each box has two properties data and next(bridge to the next element).

Every linkedList has one special box called the head which is the only element you know of(Gateway to the list) and if you need other elements of the list you follow the chain of bridges.

Now when you say things linke cur=head or prev= head you are just making copies of that gateway to the list so that you can iterate over the list by saying cur = cur.next and still keep the original gateway(head) intact.

what cur = cur.next does is simply look at cur's next node through the bridge and update cur to point directly to that next node its just like you are crossing the bride.

Comment: so the whole point of having cur or prev is to traverse without changing the head since there is no way to do it just using head right?

Comment: You could do it using just `head`, but if you did, you'd lose the pointer to the head of the list and the entire list would be lost forever. `head` *must always* be pointing to the head node of the list, so we create temporary runner nodes like `cur` and `prev` to perform the traversal and removal work while maintaining `head`. You could think of `cur` and `prev` a bit like the `i` index in a `for` loop. It's something necessary to walk the list.